# How to fix compile error "This function or variable may be unsafe" (strcpy)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I was seeing an old simple algorithm I had done a while ago. I did it using dev-c ++, but now I compiled it in visual studio and it doesn't work. Visual studio compiler says: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. (line 17)

In this easy project you will type a phrase, then you get the phrase translated in hex (each character).

So why dev-c++ doesn't tell me that? Did I make any mistakes? Or not... The code is ok? I want to understand that because it's not the first time i receive that error.

Code execution example:

Please insert a phrase:    hello world!
The string -hello world!- converted in hex is
68 65 6c 6c 6f
20 77 6f 72 6c
64 21

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string phrase;
    char* chArray;

    cout << "Pls insert a phrase:\t";
    getline(cin, phrase);

    chArray = new char[phrase.size() + 1];
    strcpy(chArray, phrase.c_str());         //THE ERROR IS HERE!

    cout << "The string -" << phrase << "- converted in hex is\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < static_cast<int>(phrase.size() + 1); i++)
    {
        int ch = (int)chArray[i-1];
        cout << setbase(16) << ch << " ";
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `std::string` and a c-string?  `chArray` is not needed, just use `phrase`.

Comment: Use `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to disable the warning.  The warning is there because a team at Microsoft identified standard C functions that they deemed potential security risks.

Comment: As an aside, avoid this: `static_cast<int>(phrase.size() + 1)` Just use a `size_t` instead of an `int`

Comment: OK, hopefully you have your question answered, but really why does `chArray` exist at all? Why don't you just write `int ch = (int)phrase[i-1];`? You can use `[]` on a `std::string`.

Comment: The next question is why you are looping from 1 upto size() + 1 and then subtracting 1 from `i`? Why not just loop from 0 upto size() and not subtract 1 from `i`.

Comment: Upgrade: i know that i can use #pragma warning(disable:4996) to disable crt warnings (but i want undestand the error, and if my code is right).

Comment: A range-based for loop would also simplify this a bit. `for  (char ch:phrase) { cout << setbase(16) << (int)ch << " "; ... }`

Comment: @Riccardo Your code is correct but could be improved.

Comment: @user4581301: I'd prefer [std::hex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) instead of `setbase(16)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get this warning when you use any of the "unsafe" byte copying functions. It's mostly specific to MSVC.

To fix it, use [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) which requires you to also pass a maximum number of bytes to copy (which should be the size of the destination buffer). This prevents buffer overflows.

```
strcpy_s(chArray, phrase.size()+1, phrase.c_str());
```

That said, it's easier to use `std::string` for all this in C++

Answer (score 6):

> Visual studio compiler says: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.

This is because you've used `strcpy`, and your compiler considers it a potentially unsafe function. The purpose of the warning is to inform you of this perceived lack of safety. The message advises you how to disable the warning in case you wish to keep using the function.

The typical, safer alternative is to use `std::string` instead. In case of your particular program, the use of `strcpy` seems completely redundant. Instead of `chArray[i-1]`, you could use `phrase[i-1]`.

> So why dev-c++ doesn't tell me that?

Diagnostic messages are up to discretion of the implementation. You're using another compiler with this IDE, and that one does not warn you for using `strcpy`.

> Did I make any mistakes?

Someone might argue that the choice to use `strcpy` is a mistake. But it's a mistake because it is easy to misuse by accident. As far as I can tell, you've used it correctly.

That said, part of the unsafety is that incorrect use is not necessarily easy to recognise. If it was easy, then the compiler would tell you when you use it incorrectly. But it's not easy, and the compiler cannot do that in general.

---

Besides the use of `strcpy`, there is another potential issue: You leak the memory that you allocate for the character array.